# Accessing prototype method on variable instance

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var Foo = (function () {

    var cls = function () {
        this.prototype = {
            sayhi: function () {
                alert('hi');
            }
        };
    };

    cls.staticMethod = function () {};

    return cls;

})();

var f = new Foo();
```

Why can't i access my `sayhi` method? Doesn't `this` refer to the `cls` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to set the `prototype` property on every *instance* of `cls`. What you actually want to do is set the `prototype` property of `cls` itself:

```
var Foo = (function () {

    var cls = function () {}; // Constructor function

    cls.prototype = { // Prototype of constructor is inherited by instances
        sayhi: function () {
            alert('hi');
        }
    };

    return cls;

})();
```

Comment: Good answer. Do you know what I'm missing here http://jsfiddle.net/6Wqsm/3/? The output is `cls {}, 
cls {sayhi: function}`, but aren't both using the same prototype and should therefore share the `sayhi` function?

Comment: No, because the prototype is overwritten with a new object each time you call `cls`. Setting the prototype inside the constructor will cause all sorts of problems. For example, try `window.f instanceof foo` in your example - it will return `false`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about the overwrite part. Thank you.